# RecyclerView programmatically click - performClick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i'm searching function that programmatically click method. so i found some method. 'performClick()'

like that :

```
recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.performClick();
```

but it dosen't work in my case. I can't find solution. How do i use the performClick in Activity???

my Adapter - ViewHolder:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView virtNo;
    private TextView score01;
    private TextView score02;
    private TextView score03;
    private TextView totalScore;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.virtNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_virtNo);
        this.score01 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_score01);
        this.score02 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_score02);
        this.score03 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_score03);
        this.totalScore = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_totalScore);
        this.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_item_score);

        virtNo.setOnClickListener(this);
        score01.setOnClickListener(this);
        score02.setOnClickListener(this);
        score03.setOnClickListener(this);
        score10.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), items.get(getAdapterPosition()));
    }
}

public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener<Score> onClickListener) {
    this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
}

public interface OnClickListener<T> {
    void onClick(View v, int position, T item);
}
```

my Adapter - onBindViewHolder

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Score item = items.get(position);
    holder.virtNo.setText(item.virtNo);
    holder.score01.setText(item.score01);
    holder.score02.setText(item.score02);
    holder.score03.setText(item.score03);
    holder.totalScore.setText(itemSum(item));
    }
}
```

Comment: i solved my problem, but... a little strange way... anyway, i solved... so hard life...

Comment: How did you solve it? I am very eager to know.

Comment: @AliNfr i can't write english very well, so i can't explain to you. so sorry... and now i don't understand my code.. ㅠㅠ so sorry....

Comment: can you share how you fixed it, you dont need to write in english just answer your question with code @Ryujihoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to keep things easy to understand here, it is a complete example for listening to click event on individual items in `RecyclerView`, there are other ways to do it as well. This code works, You may modify it as it fits you, in case you have any question write them in comments. code is also available at [GitHub](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/recyclerview/list/activities/RecyclerViewOneActivity.java)

```
public class RecyclerViewOneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view_one);
        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewOneActivity_RecyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("first");
        strings.add("second");
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), strings);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<String> strings;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> strings) {
            this.context = context;
            this.strings = strings;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item_recycler_view_one, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
            return myViewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final String text = this.strings.get(position);
            holder.textView.setText("" + text);
            holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, ""+text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return strings.size();
        }

        class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private LinearLayout linearLayout;
            private TextView textView;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.single_item_recycler_view_one_linear_layout);
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.single_item_recycler_view_one_textView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**single_item_recycler_view_one.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/single_item_recycler_view_one_linear_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/single_item_recycler_view_one_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj Nimgade, I will try it